# broadcast a message among set of raspberry Pis

Tags: python, sockets

I want to broadcast a message among four raspberry Pis . I programmed the code By socket programming in python with UDP protocol . In order to send the message I used the broadcast IP address (192.168.0.255) and I test that in terminal on my computer it is work , but when I execute the same code on the Pi it is not working and no message is sent . When I send a message between two Pis and use (IP + port) it is work and the message is sent . 
Did any one know what I must to change in my code ?? or in my Pi?? How I can broadcast this message ??

I also use the instruction (('', UDP_PORT)) and not work on Pi.

```
#Client.py

import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
UDP_IP = "192.168.0.255"
UDP_PORT = 50000
MSG = 'Hello, World!'
MESSAGE = str.encode(MSG)
print (("message:"), MSG )
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
sock.close()

#server.py

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDP_IP = "192.168.0.101"
UDP_PORT = 5005
s.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print('socket is created')
while True:
data ,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print (('received message:') , data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Can you clarify _when I execute the same code on the Pi it is not working and no message is sent_ and _I send a message between two Pis and use (IP + port) it is work and the message is sent_ ?

Comment: One likely problem is that your client sends to port 50000 but your server is listening on port 5005.

Comment: Alexander Cécile  ... I mean I test this code on my computer using  three separated  terminals (cmd ) It was ok .. but when I write the same code on raspberry pi , It wasn't work .. When I change the broadcast IP address and use the IP of raspberry pi and send a message between them the message was sent ..  I think the problem is with broadcast IP address

Comment: Jeremy Friesner .. I changed the port number and the problem is still exists